# How to create an ODBC connection using IBM data studio?

Tags: database, odbc, ibm-data-studio

I am trying to connect to a specific database using the ODBC connection. I have IBM data studio installed. If anyone can give guidance how to connect to a database via the ODBC connection using the tool IBM data studio. I tried using the ODBC credentials but I am getting error unable to connect.

thanks in advance

Comment: IBM data studio is java based and so uses JDBC. You have to be more specific about what DBMS you are trying to connect to and what is the complete error text you get.